# How to link Docusign eSignature account to existing Docusign Admin (Organization)

Tags: docusignapi

I have two accounts for DocuSign, one for demo, and one for production. While implementing JWT Grant oAuth2 workflow, I created a DocuSign Admin (Organization), through demo account . Now, how can I link production account to the existing organization to enable oAuth for production account?

Comment: Why didn't you just create the org in your production account? If I understand your ask currently, you may need to reach out to customer service to get this corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer (demo) environment is separate from the production environments.

You should connect your production account to a production DocuSign Organization. If you don't see the organization options, talk with your DocuSign sales person to have the option enabled.

After you have your production organization setup, you can claim the same DNS domain(s) that you claimed with your demo organization.

Because the demo organization is separate from the production organization, both can claim the same DNS domain.